# how to use array in for loop using php

Tags: php

Iam inviting facebook friends id using graph api, and tagging these friends in a picture, this code is storing my friends ids in multidimensional array. but there is some error because these arrays are not separating by comma (,)
as printing of array using foreach loop, please help me how comma separater would come between these array, i hope u understand that what i actually wants to do, please print this array in correct way, i have mentioned down what i actually want to get.

```
<?php
$friend_array   =   array();

$searchIDs  = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['searchIDs'])));

if( $searchIDs > 0 )
{
    $friends_array  =   explode(",",$searchIDs);
    $x      =   100;
    $y      =   50;

    for( $f=0 ; $f<count($friends_array) ; $f++ ) {
        $tag_frd[]  =   array(
        'tag_uid'=> $friends_array[$f],
        'x'      => $x,
        'y'      => $y
        );
}

print_r($tag_frd);
//print_r implode(",",$tag_frd);

?>


***This is my OUTPUT:***

Array
(
[0]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>1321321
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
)

[1]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>132132100400001
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
)

[2]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>132135454321
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
)

)


***AND I WANTS THIS OUTPUT:***

Array
(
[0]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>1321321
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
),

[1]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>132132100400001
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
),

[2]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>132135454321
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
)

)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post expected output

Comment: Can you post the original array and the expected output

Comment: Your output and the output you want are the same.

Comment: You can use for each to print the expected output as per your wish

Comment: ***AND I WANTS THIS OUTPUT:***

Array
(
[0]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>1321321
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
),

[1]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>132132100400001
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
),

[2]=>Array
(
    [tag_uid]=>132135454321
    [x]=>100
    [y]=>50
)

)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `foreach`?

```
$tag_frd = array();
foreach ($friends_array as $friend) {
    $tag_frd[] = array(
        'tag_uid' => $friend,
        'x'       => $x,
        'y'       => $y
    );
}
```

Comment: because i have more than one friend who i wants to tag in my picture, and $tag_frd[] array is used to tag single friend, so iam using for loop

Comment: @user3122331 So, you need to use array of arrays which means object where index 0 represents first $tag_frd[] and one represent second $tag_frd[] and so on..

Comment: try to use foreach, that makes more easier for you!